# Error in Manifest after copy-paste code from google samples

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to add Google Analytics to my app. I made the following changes according to instructions from google:

Code

```
<service android:name="com.DriverNotes.AndroidMobileClient.GcmIntentService" />
<service android:name=" com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
```

but I am getting this error in the Manifest file:

**Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]**

I tried removing the ' ' (space) symbol in `...oid:name=" com.google.androi...` but after restart it returns.

Comment: `<service android:name=" com.google` You **need** the **"** characters. But **remove the space**!!

Comment: I remove space but it return after rerun

Comment: Because you are trying to remove the **"**, so it readds it. But it includes the space too.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what you mean

Comment: Make sure you're editing the correct manifest; that is, not the generated one.

Comment: Mike, write as answer - its correct

Comment: I mean: `<service android:name=" com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />` = **WRONG**. `<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />` = **CORRECT**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your IDE encounters a build error in the manifest, it is probably opening the build-generated manifest file to display the error. Any edits to this file have no effect, as it will be overwritten during the next build. Make sure you edit instead the `AndroidManifest.xml` file located somewhere under your `/src` directory.