# manifest keep adding error line

Tags: java, android, xml, manifest

I was building my app in Android platform.
I was trying to put the buttons right above the softkeyboard.
So I added

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

and didn't get the result I want. However I was searching on I read a 
solution who used

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

and he said it would work.

Therefore, I tried this line. Instead of having result what I want,
The log said,

Error:(17) No resource identifier found for attribute 'fitsSysstemWindows' in package 'android'

I removed this line and tried to compile the app and it keeps adding 
this line(the one I removed) and throws error.

My manifest look like this (don't care about package name I just changed it because I can't reveal what I am currently working on

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="blahbalh"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="blahblah.MainActivity"
        android:fitsSysstemWindows="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"     />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in Manifest after copy-paste code from google samples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800916/error-in-manifest-after-copy-paste-code-from-google-samples)

Comment: Also, you misspelled `fitsSystemWindows`, and that attribute doesn't go in the manifest anyway.

Comment: You misspelled fitsSystemWindows.  Move that attribute to the layout corresponding to that activity, place it in the button applicable button : android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

Comment: @ScottS I removed the fitsSystemWIndows and added it to the layout that corresponds to the activity but didn't work either.

Comment: @MikeM Yes, I found that didn't go into manifest but I put it into a correct layout but didn't work.